# Convert CSV to tab delimit file in AIX server

Tags: aix, csv

I have a requirement to transform a csv to a tab delimited file. 
But the problem is, I have “,” within name field which I need to maintain.

Source:

```
Amsterdam, “last name, first name”, Europe
```

Output:

```
Amsterdam\tlast name, first name\tEurope
```

Comment: the file contains non-standard quotes

Comment: The source data when you open in Microsoft excel it maintains the data integrity as we’ll as my application which processes it. But this has to be processed by an new application which cannot differentiate between comma as delimiter and comma as part of data. Since it can handle tab delimited I am trying to change it to tab format.

Comment: do you python installed? also, what's your `awk --version`?

Comment: @user2704230 yes, tab-separated is a good alternative.  See if you can get whoever is exporting the Excel file for you to select TAB as the delimiter when they export.  otherwise your best bet would be to use a language with a real CSV parser (CSV has a lot more quirks and oddities and corner cases than most people think, and it's difficult to handle them all with just regular expressions).  perl or python, for example.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am not able to find the version ok awk on my aix server. But I do know that I am using 7.1 version of aix.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like `sed -e 's/, "/\t/g' -e 's/", /\t/g' < intput_file` would help. The `sed` expressions replace `, "` with `\t` and `",` with `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi with [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) is simple. With

`echo 'Amsterdam,"last name, first name",Europe' | \
mlr --c2t --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output cat`

You have

```
Amsterdam\tlast name, first name\tEurope
```

- `--c2t` is for `CSV to TSV`;
- `--implicit-csv-header` and `--headerless-csv-output` to set that there is no header both input and output